# How does Facebook keep track of viewed Posts?

Tags: php

I am developing an app where users can post. I want to alert users when a new post is submitted that they have not seen. The whole process is basically the way facebook is set up. However, I was wondering how I keep track of posts users have seen already.

How does facebook accomplish that?

Comment: [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: ajax can be used for polling, yes, but it cannot tell you if a user has viewed a post.

Comment: It's server-side job, not client-side. Ajax starts polling, server gives requested data.

Comment: I realize the server handles the data. The questions is how the server distinguishes from posts the user has seen, and posts the user has not seen. If you know this process is a server side job, I don't know why you even posted 'ajax' in the first place. It doesn't matter though b/c someone already posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever a user views a post (**makes a request that returns said post**), add an entry to the `views` table. Here's a simple diagram

[image: views]

That way you'd know which user viewed what. Additionally you can add a `timestamp` field to keep track of *when* the user viewed the post.

So if you you wanna know who viewed the post `666` you can simply

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN views v ON u.user_id = v.user_id
WHERE v.post_id = 666
```

You can also check if a user viewed a certain post so you can decided whether to alert him or not

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN views v ON u.user_id = v.user_id
WHERE v.post_id = 666 AND v.user_id = 1000
```

And you can work a simple logic

```php
if (lastQueryReturnedAResult){
   //User had seen the post
}else{
   alertUser();
   viewPostInDifferentColor();
}
```

**Note:** This isn't really how Facebook does it, as this method doesn't scale pretty well. But this is the basic idea.